# body centering for different devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the body centered for all devices with different screen sizes

white background portion should be centered

http://jsfiddle.net/ymnkg/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/ymnkg/1/embedded/result/

providing my code below

```
<body class="home">

    <div id="redColor">
        <header style="background-color: white; width: 1224px; margin-left: 339px;">
            <div class="inner clearfix"><div class="logo">
              <a href="">          
                  <img alt="Splitwise" class="defieLogo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/defie_logo.png">
              </a>
            </div>

        </header>
        <div id="banner" class="clearfix" style="border-bottom: 5px solid #C3C3C3; width: 1223px;">
            <div class="bx-wrapper" style="width:1227px; position:relative; margin-top: 0px;">
                <div class="bx-window" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:1227px;">
                    <ul id="slider1" style="width: 999999px; position: relative; left: -1227px;">
                        <li style="width: 1227px; float: left; list-style: none;" class="pager">
                                <a href=""><img src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/frontpage_rotate1.png" alt="banner 1" border="0"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="width: 1227px; float: left; list-style: none;" class="pager">
                                <a href=""><img src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/frontpage_rotate2.png" alt="banner 2" border="0"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="width: 1227px; float: left; list-style: none;" class="pager">
                                <a href=""><img src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/frontpage_rotate3.png" alt="banner 3" border="0"></a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section id="main" style="background-color: #646464; padding: 0px;">
            <div class="inner clearfix" style="background-color: white; width: 1223px;">
                <span style="color: #06546a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; background-color: white;">Defie Cloud Buisness Solution offers features and functionality for business - today and tomorrow</span>
                <div id="primary">
                    <section class="primary">
                        <ul style="width: 800px;">
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; font-size: 13px;">
                                <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                                    <span style="color: red;">Accounting and Finance:</span> Sales and Customer Management
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; font-size: 13px;">
                                <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                                    <span style="color: red;">Buisness Operation Package:</span> Purchasing and Vendor Management, Inventory Management, Build of Materials, Real-Time Production, Product Life Cycle, QA Management
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; font-size: 13px;">
                                <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png"><span style="color: red;">Customer Relationship Management</span>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none; font-size: 13px;">
                                <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                                <span style="color: red;">Cloud File and Document Apps:</span> Store, Manage, Share, Access and Modify anytime, anywhere on any devices
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-bottom: 5px; list-style: none;">
                                <img alt="squareList" style="margin-right: 10px; font-size: 13px;" id="logo" src="http://www.defie.co/designerImages/square_list.png">
                                <span style="color: red;">Cloud Buisness Management:</span> From Front to Back Office, z from Hardware to Software, from Desktops to Servers Solution and Support
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
        <ul id="eM" style="width: 1228px; margin-left: 80px; background-color:#646464;">
            <li id="eMli"><a id="eMlia" href="#home">Product</a></li>
            <li id="eMli"><a id="eMlia" href="#news">Solutions</a></li>
            <li id="eMli"><a id="eMlia" href="#contact">Solutions</a></li>
            <li id="eMli"><a id="eMlia" href="#about">Partners</a></li>
            <li id="eMli"><a id="eMlia" href="#news">About</a></li>
            <li id="eMli"><a id="eMlia" href="#contact">Home</a></li>
            <li id="eMli"><a id="eMlia" href="#about">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use percentages instead of pixels. Or you could use [Repsonsive Booststrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) which shine in this aspect.

Comment: anywhere you have a pixel value in your css, change it to a pixel value

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to make the body centered for all devices with different screen sizes

All devices have different resulotions. So dont use pixels, use percentages. So that it will acquire only the available width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
.home{
    width: 85%; //Give a width so you can see it is centered
    margin: 0 auto; //This is for centering the page
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

You can write [css media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to make it looking good in small screen.